# Problem on querystring in SQL cmd

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, query-string

I have the next code:

```
    private int bla(out int itemsMin, out int purchase)
{
    string ID = (Request.QueryString["Ttrsid"] ?? "0").ToString();
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=*****;Integrated Security=False;");
        string commandtext = "SELECT Min FROM myItems WHERE itemId=@ID";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);

        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID); //Adds the ID we got before to the SQL command
        itemsMin = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        string commandtext2 = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM purchase";
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandtext2, connection);
        purchase = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar();
    }



    return 0;



}
```

The code is for two labels that i use - one to get the minimum number (itemsMin), and the other is for the count of the purchase.

I'm using the querystring to get the values by the itemid that the user watching on him now.. (from the address bar (for example: items.aspx?Ttrsid=5 so i want to see the minimum number of the Ttrsid = 5).

Everything works fine. when i'm on the Ttrsid = 1 , Ttrsid = 2 - i get what i want, but when i'm enterd to the Ttrsid = 3 and so on - that's give me the error:

> System.NullReferenceException

To the line:

> itemsMin = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

.. and it's not null.. the item have all the required fields like Ttrsid = 2 .... so what wrong here?

The next code is the use of the command above:

```
        int i, p; // variable need not be initialized
    Console.WriteLine(bla(out i, out p));
    if (i < p)
    {
        haha.Visible = true;

    }
    else
    {
        haha2.Visible = true;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(p);
```

i = itemsMin , p = purchase .

Comment: Are you sure, you have data against ID =3 or 4, 5 ?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. i cheked it on query in the SQL server

Comment: Can you share us the same query that you have test in SQL server?

Comment: Yes.. SELECT Min FROM myItems WHERE itemId = 5

Comment: what if Ttrsid is: 0';DROP TABLE `myItems`;--

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is no matching row in the db, so no rows returned. Sanity-check the result from ExecuteScalar - in particular, check it for null before casting to int. It is also possible that the column contains a null, but maybe I'd expect DBNull.Value for that.

Also - use `using` on all the `IDisposable` objects here; the connection and command in particular.

Comment: thanks. i've cheked that on the SQL server in query - and i got the right result. but on the page is still the problem.

Comment: @Bside humour me - check it ***in the code*** anyway. And here's a thought - in the db is the id a string or an integer?

Comment: in the db the id is an integer

Comment: @Bside you have a string-based parameter; that won't help... Use int.Parse to get an integer before adding as a parameter - it will help performance among other things

Comment: Thanks marc. how can i do here the int.parse? i cant thinking anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume below pasted variable is a int type variable

```
purchase = (int)
```

Hence you may not be able to convert null values to an integer so try it changing the sql command as below

```
SELECT isNull(COUNT (*),0) FROM purchase
```

@Marc I'm really sorry about it

Don't you want to specify a column name next to the min statement? As below

```
SELECT Min(columnName) FROM myItems WHERE itemId=@ID ?
```

Comment: The line in question is itemsMin, not purchase

Comment: Also, WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING, THANKS.

Comment: Finally, COUNT would return 0, not a null